# Parsing the end of a phrase before the beginning in Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to get Boost.Spirit to parse MSVC mangled symbols. These take the form:

`?myvolatileStaticMember@myclass@@2HC`

which means "volatile int myclass::myvolatileStaticMember".

The "key" to the parse is the double at symbol "@@". Prior to the @@ is the name of the symbol which consists of a C++ identifier followed by zero or more "@" additional identifiers to fully represent the symbol in its absolute namespace hierarchy. After the @@ is the specification of what the identifier is (a variable, a function etc.)

Now, I can get Boost.Spirit to parse *either* the part preceding the @@ *or* the part after the @@. I haven't figured out yet how to get Boost.Spirit to find the @@ and feed what comes before that to one custom parser and what comes after it to a different custom parser.

Here's my parser for the part preceding the @@:

```c
// This grammar is for a MSVC mangled identifier
template<typename iterator> struct msvc_name : grammar<iterator, SymbolType(), locals<SymbolType, string>>
{
    SymbolTypeDict &typedict;
    void name_writer(SymbolType &val, const string &i) const { val.name=i; }
    void dependent_writer(SymbolType &val, const string &i) const
    {
        SymbolTypeDict::const_iterator dt=typedict.find(i);
        if(dt==typedict.end())
        {
            auto _dt=typedict.emplace(make_pair(i, SymbolType(SymbolTypeQualifier::None, SymbolTypeType::Namespace, i)));
            dt=_dt.first;
        }
        val.dependents.push_back(&dt->second);
    }
    // These work by spreading the building of a templated type over multiple calls using local variables _a and _b
    // We accumulate template parameters into _a and accumulate mangled symbolness into _b
    void begin_template_dependent_writer(SymbolType &, SymbolType &a, string &b, const string &i) const
    {
        a=SymbolType(SymbolTypeQualifier::None, SymbolTypeType::Class, i);
        b=i;
    }
    void add_template_constant_dependent_writer(SymbolType &a, string &b, long long constant) const
    {
        string i("_c"+to_string(constant));
        SymbolTypeDict::const_iterator dt=typedict.find(i);
        if(dt==typedict.end())
        {
            auto _dt=typedict.emplace(make_pair(i, SymbolType(SymbolTypeQualifier::None, SymbolTypeType::Constant, to_string(constant))));
            dt=_dt.first;
        }
        a.templ_params.push_back(&dt->second);
        b.append(i);
    }
    void add_template_type_dependent_writer(SymbolType &a, string &b, SymbolTypeType type) const
    {
        string i("_t"+to_string(static_cast<int>(type)));
        SymbolTypeDict::const_iterator dt=typedict.find(i);
        if(dt==typedict.end())
        {
            auto _dt=typedict.emplace(make_pair(i, SymbolType(SymbolTypeQualifier::None, type)));
            dt=_dt.first;
        }
        a.templ_params.push_back(&dt->second);
        b.append(i);
    }
    void finish_template_dependent_writer(SymbolType &val, SymbolType &a, string &b) const
    {
        SymbolTypeDict::const_iterator dt=typedict.find(b);
        if(dt==typedict.end())
        {
            auto _dt=typedict.emplace(make_pair(b, a));
            dt=_dt.first;
        }
        val.dependents.push_back(&dt->second);
    }
    msvc_name(SymbolTypeDict &_typedict) : msvc_name::base_type(start), typedict(_typedict)
    {
        identifier=+(char_ - '@');
        identifier.name("identifier");
        template_dependent_identifier=+(char_ - '@');
        template_dependent_identifier.name("template_dependent_identifier");
        dependent_identifier=+(char_ - '@');
        dependent_identifier.name("dependent_identifier");
        start = identifier [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::name_writer, this, _val, _1) ] >> *(
            lit("@@") >> eps
            | (("@?$" > template_dependent_identifier [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::begin_template_dependent_writer, this, _val, _a, _b, _1) ])
                > "@" > +(( "$0" > constant [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::add_template_constant_dependent_writer, this, _a, _b, _1) ])
                    | type [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::add_template_type_dependent_writer, this, _a, _b, _1) ])
                >> eps [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::finish_template_dependent_writer, this, _val, _a, _b) ])
            | ("@" > dependent_identifier [ boost::phoenix::bind(&msvc_name::dependent_writer, this, _val, _1) ]))
            ;
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
        start.name("msvc_name");
        on_error<boost::spirit::qi::fail, iterator>(start,
            cerr << boost::phoenix::val("Parsing error: Expected ") << _4 << boost::phoenix::val(" here: \"")
                << boost::phoenix::construct<string>(_3, _2) << boost::phoenix::val("\"") << endl);
    }

    rule<iterator, SymbolType(), locals<SymbolType, string>> start;
    rule<iterator, string()> identifier, template_dependent_identifier, dependent_identifier;
    msvc_type type;
    msvc_constant<iterator> constant;
};
```

You'll note the "lit("@@") >> eps" where I'm trying to get it to stop matching once it sees a @@. Now here is the part which is supposed to match a full mangled symbol:

```c
template<typename iterator> struct msvc_symbol : grammar<iterator, SymbolType()>
{
    SymbolTypeDict &typedict;
    /* The key to Microsoft symbol mangles is the operator '@@' which consists of a preamble
    and a postamble. Immediately following the '@@' operator is:
    Variable:
    3<type><storage class>
    Static member variable:
    2<type><storage class>
    Function:
    <near|far><calling conv>[<stor ret>]   <return type>[<parameter type>...]<term>Z
    <Y   |Z  ><A|E|G       >[<?A|?B|?C|?D>]<MangledToSymbolTypeType...>      <@>Z
    Member Function:
    <protection>[<const>]<calling conv>[<stor ret>]   <return type>[<parameter type>...]<term>Z
    <A-V       >[<A-D>  ]<A|E|G       >[<?A|?B|?C|?D>]<MangledToSymbolTypeType...>      <@>Z
    */
    msvc_symbol(SymbolTypeDict &_typedict) : msvc_symbol::base_type(start), typedict(_typedict), name(_typedict), variable(_typedict)
    {
        start="?" >> name >> ("@@" >> variable);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
        on_error<boost::spirit::qi::fail, iterator>(start,
            cerr << boost::phoenix::val("Parsing error: Expected ") << _4 << boost::phoenix::val(" here: \"")
                << boost::phoenix::construct<string>(_3, _2) << boost::phoenix::val("\"") << endl);
    }

    rule<iterator, SymbolType()> start;
    msvc_name<iterator> name;
    msvc_variable<iterator> variable;
};
```

So, it matches the "?" easily enough ;). The problem is that it sends everything after the "?" to the msvc_name parser, so instead of the bit from @@ onwards going to msvc_variable and the remainder going to msvc_name, msvc_name consumes everything up to and including @@. This isn't intuitive, as one would have thought that the brackets mean to do that thing first.

Therefore if I replace:

   `start="?" >> name >> ("@@" >> variable);`

with

   `start="?" >> name >> variable;`

... it all works fine.

However I'd really prefer not to do it this way. Ideally, I want Boost.Spirit to split at @@ cleanly in msvc_symbol and "do the right thing" as it were. I'm thinking I'm probably not thinking recursively enough? Either way I'm stumped.

Note: Yes I am aware I can break the string at @@ and run two separate parsers. That isn't what I'm asking - rather, I'm asking how to configure Boost.Spirit to parse the end of a phrase before the beginning.

Note also: I'm aware a skipper could be used to make the @@ whitespace and do the split that way. The problem is that what comes before the @@ is very specific, as is what comes after the @@. Therefore it's not really whitespace.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help. From searching Google and Stackoverflow for questions related to this one, overcoming Boost.Spirit's "left-to-right greediness" is a problem for a lot of people.

Niall

Comment: Ah. I thought I remembered this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you can do a number of things:

1. explicitely  disallow the double "@@" where you expect "@". See also

   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html
   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/not_predicate.html
2. tokenize first (use Spirit Lex?)

Here I show you a working example of the first approach:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename T> T reversed(T c) {  return T(c.rbegin(), c.rend()); }

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    const std::string input("?myvolatileStaticMember@myclass@@2HC");

    auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);

    auto identifier = +~qi::char_("@");
    auto delimit    = qi::lit("@") - "@@";

    std::vector<std::string> qualifiedName;
    std::string typeId;

    if (qi::parse(f,l,
                '?' >> identifier % delimit >> "@@" >> +qi::char_,
                qualifiedName,
                typeId))
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
        qualifiedName = reversed(qualifiedName);
        std::cout << "Qualified name: "  << format(auto_ % "::" << "\n", qualifiedName);
        std::cout << "Type indication: '" << typeId << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Qualified name: myclass::myvolatileStaticMember
Type indication: '2HC'
```

Comment: Outstanding! And the bleeding obvious - as I have slowly come to grok, Boost Spirit really does always parse exclusively left to right, so '"@" > identifier' *will* match the @ and then expectation fail if identifier doesn't match. As a result, one needs to think in terms of "@" - "@@" being the match string. And thank you very much indeed for pointing it out to me. Niall